# Why does getting a data-attribute within a loop work, but still throws an error?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some input elements and I want to create a reset button, so that I can programatically revert their `values` to their original state.

Here is my code:

```js
let people = document.getElementsByClassName('person')

function reset() {
  for (var key in people) {
    let string = people[key].dataset.name
    people[key].value = string
  }
}

let app = document.getElementById('app')
let button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerHTML = "reset"
button.addEventListener('click', reset)
app.append(button)
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input class="person" data-name="John" value="John">
  <input class="person" data-name="Steve" value="Steve">
  <input class="person" data-name="Peter" value="Peter">
</div>
```

This actually works as intended, but I get an error saying that the value of `'data-name'` cannot be read, but this cannot be true as the function works as intended.

Does anyone know what is happening here and how I can fix this?

Comment: I realize that this is not your specific question but you don't have to scan the DOM again for people if id #app has only input.person top-level children.  You can use `app.children()` to get the HTML live collection; and, if you prefer, you could use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the collection to an array, although that is not necessary since the items in the collection can be accessed in order of DOM using integer index anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in` iterates over all enumerable properties in not only the object itself, but also in all objects in the internal prototype chain. Log the key, and you'll see:

```js
let people = document.getElementsByClassName('person')

function reset() {
  for (var key in people) {
    console.log(key);
  }
}
reset();
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input class="person" data-name="John" value="John">
  <input class="person" data-name="Steve" value="Steve">
  <input class="person" data-name="Peter" value="Peter">
</div>
```

The HTMLCollection has more enumerable properties than just `0`, `1`, and `2`, so trying to access the `.dataset` on those *other* properties fails.

Use `for..of` instead, to invoke the collection's iterator (which will only iterate over the elements in the collection, as desired).

```js
let people = document.getElementsByClassName('person')

function reset() {
  for (const input of people) {
    input.value = input.dataset.name;
  }
}
let app = document.getElementById('app')
let button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerHTML = "reset"
button.addEventListener('click', reset)
app.append(button)
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input class="person" data-name="John" value="John">
  <input class="person" data-name="Steve" value="Steve">
  <input class="person" data-name="Peter" value="Peter">
</div>
```

In general, I'd suggest avoiding `in` loops usually - often, `for..of` or `Object.keys` or `Object.entries` work better.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code here

```
for (var key in people)
```

should be

```
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
```

as the for...in... loop will also get the `length` property of the `people` HTMLCollection. You would then be accessing the `value` property of `people.length`, which does not exist.

Completed Code:

```js
let people = document.getElementsByClassName('person')

function reset() {
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  let string = people[i].dataset.name
  people[i].value = string
}
}

let app = document.getElementById('app')
let button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerHTML = "reset"
    button.addEventListener('click',reset)
    app.append(button)
```

```html
<div id="app">
<input class="person" data-name="John" value="John">
<input class="person" data-name="Steve" value="Steve">
<input class="person" data-name="Peter" value="Peter">
</div>
```